# Minimal generating set of Rubik's Cube group

Tags: group-theory, permutations, recreational-mathematics, rubiks-cube

The Rubik's Cube group is generated by the six moves $\{F,B,U,D,L,R\}$. However, is this the *minimal* generating set for the group? In other words, can I simulate the move $F$ just by making the moves $B,U,D,L,R$? If I try this out on an actual Rubik's cube, it doesn't seem quite simple (starting from a solved state twist the front face and try to solve the cube without turning it again), but I don't see any reason why it would be impossible either.

Answer (score 23):

Yes, you can achieve one of the generators from the other $5$. I have some old "Notes on Rubik's Magic Cube" by David Singmaster, according to which $D^{-1}$ is equal to:

$$R^2L^2UF^2B^2UF^2R^2F^2B^2U^2L^2U^2L^2R^2U^2R^2U^2R^2F^2U^{-1}R^2B^2R^2L^2F^2L^2UB^2F^2U $$

I have tried this out now, and it works. It is attributed to Roger Penrose.

You cannot dispense with any more of the standard generators - you need at least $5$ of them.

But the group is a $2$-generator group. Two randomly chosen elements have a reasonably high probability of generating the whole group.

Comment: A reference for those claims would be nice, perhaps a link to the notes if possible?

Comment: You could always play around with GAP: http://www.gap-system.org/Doc/Examples/rubik.html

Comment: This question gives the two generators and a reference to the notes: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1641110/proof-that-the-rubik-s-cube-group-is-2-generated?rq=1

Comment: Are you sure that's the sequence? It isn't working for me.

Comment: I am sorry, the sequence I posted yesterday was a component of the solution rather than the complete solution. Unfortuantely, I had Singmaster's notes in my room at the univeristy and a cube at home, so I could not check it directly. I have checked it now, and it works.

Comment: Is the sequence read right to left or left to right?

Answer (score 8):

> If I try this out on an actual Rubik's cube, it doesn't seem quite simple (starting from a solved state twist the front face and try to solve the cube without turning it again)

It depends on your solution procedure. With the one I use, it turns out that I'm actually only turning the bottom side: (a) while assembling the initial cross (which is easy to do in other ways), and (b) while orienting the top-layer corners at the end (which can be done without turning that side by orienting the cube differently in this phase). So solving after a $B$ quarter-turn without using any $B$s was easy for me.

Keeping *two* of the sides immovable is not possible, however. If the two sides you won't turn are neighbors, the edge piece they have in common cannot move at all; if they are opposites, the 24 stickers on the edge pieces split into two orbits, so it's not possible to flip an edge anymore.

---

If we don't require the generators to be single twists, we can get down to two. (Of course we can't get down to one, because a one-generator group is abelian, and the Rubik group isn't). Michael Lugo's comment on Derek's answer gives a set of two somewhat optimized generators, but we can also do:

- Let $X$ be a combination that cycles $7$ of the corners, cycles $3$ of the edges, keeps at least one edge unchanged, and flips at least one edge that it doesn't move.
- Let $Y$ be a combination that interchanges $2$ corners, cycles $10$ edges, keeps at least one corner unchanged, and twists at least one of the corners that it doesn't move.

such that exactly one corner and one edge is moved by both $X$ and $Y$.

- Using $X$ and $Y$ we can permute the *edges* any way we like, while messing up the corners.
- Now $X^3$ cycles the 7 corners (even corner partity), leaving all edges in place, and $Y$ transposes 2 corners (odd corner parity), while also cycling $10$ edges. We can achieve any *even* permutation of the corners by $X^3$s and $Y$s, and since there will be an even number of $Y$s, we can get the 10-cycle of edges back to its starting position without disturbing the corners by doing one or more $Y^2$s afterwards.

Thus $X$ and $Y$ are sufficient to realize any legal *permutation* of the cubies, ignoring the orientations of each cubie.

However, now $X^{21}$ doesn't move any cubie, so $X^{63}$ keeps all cubies in place and doesn't twist any corners. But $X^{63}$ does flip at least one edge and leaves at least one edge unflipped, so by combining appropriate conjugations of $X^{63}$ we can achieve any legal combination of edge flips.

Likewise, $Y^{10}$ does not move any cubie, and $Y^{20}$ keeps all cubies in place without flipping any edge, but does twist one corner and leaves another corner unchanged. So appropriate conjugations of $Y^{20}$ combine into any legal combination of corner turns.

Comment: Are the conjugations you list in the last two paragraphs only by $X$ or $Y$? Wouldn't that be required to have them generate the group?

Comment: @RossMillikan: Yes, they are only by combinations of $X$s and $Y$s. In the previous paragraphs we have seen that those is enough to get the edges (or corners) into any _location_ we want, which is enough for this purpose. It doesn't matter which _orientation_ we get the cubies into before we do $X^{63}$ or $Y^{20}$, because orientation changes commute with $X^{63}$ and $Y^{20}$ anyway.

Comment: I wonder what are the orders of X, Y, and the commutation relation between them, so that we may write a presentation of the cube group with two generators

Answer (score 2):

The solution alg mentioned earlier is 31 FTM and 57 QTM.

However, using Cube Explorer, I found the following optimal solutions for D and D2:

**D** =

R L F2 B2 R' L' **U** R L F2 B2 R' L'  (13f*, 17q*)

R L F2 B2 R' L' **U** R' L' F2 B2 R L  (13f*, 17q*)

R L' F2 B2 R L' **U** R L' F2 B2 R L'  (13f*, 17q*)

R L' F2 B2 R L' **U** R' L F2 B2 R' L  (13f*, 17q*)

R' L F2 B2 R' L **U** R L' F2 B2 R L'  (13f*, 17q*)

R' L F2 B2 R' L **U** R' L F2 B2 R' L  (13f*, 17q*)

R' L' F2 B2 R L **U** R L F2 B2 R' L'  (13f*, 17q*)

R' L' F2 B2 R L **U** R' L' F2 B2 R L  (13f*, 17q*)

F B R2 L2 F' B' **U** F B R2 L2 F' B'  (13f*, 17q*)

F B R2 L2 F' B' **U** F' B' R2 L2 F B  (13f*, 17q*)

F B' R2 L2 F B' **U** F B' R2 L2 F B'  (13f*, 17q*)

F B' R2 L2 F B' **U** F' B R2 L2 F' B  (13f*, 17q*)

F' B R2 L2 F' B **U** F B' R2 L2 F B'  (13f*, 17q*)

F' B R2 L2 F' B **U** F' B R2 L2 F' B  (13f*, 17q*)

F' B' R2 L2 F B **U** F B R2 L2 F' B'  (13f*, 17q*)

F' B' R2 L2 F B **U** F' B' R2 L2 F B  (13f*, 17q*)

Curiously, D2 requires fewer moves in either metric:

**D2** =

R L' F2 U2 B2 R' L U2 F2  (9f*, 14q*)

R2 U2 F' B L2 U2 R2 F B'  (9f*, 14q*)

R' L B2 U2 F2 R L' U2 B2  (9f*, 14q*)

F B' L2 U2 R2 F' B U2 L2  (9f*, 14q*)

F2 U2 R L' B2 U2 F2 R' L  (9f*, 14q*)

F' B R2 U2 L2 F B' U2 R2  (9f*, 14q*)

L2 U2 F B' R2 U2 L2 F' B  (9f*, 14q*)

B2 U2 R' L F2 U2 B2 R L'  (9f*, 14q*)

R2 F2 B2 L2 **U2** R2 F2 B2 L2  (9f*)

R2 F2 B2 L2 **U2** L2 F2 B2 R2  (9f*)

F2 R2 L2 B2 **U2** F2 R2 L2 B2  (9f*)

F2 R2 L2 B2 **U2** B2 R2 L2 F2  (9f*)

L2 F2 B2 R2 **U2** R2 F2 B2 L2  (9f*)

L2 F2 B2 R2 **U2** L2 F2 B2 R2  (9f*)

B2 R2 L2 F2 **U2** F2 R2 L2 B2  (9f*)

B2 R2 L2 F2 **U2** B2 R2 L2 F2  (9f*)

and if X in {R L', R' L}, Y in {F B', F' B}, then

D2 =

**U2** X Y X' Y X' Y' (14q*)

**U2** Y X Y' X Y' X' (14q*)

**U**(') X Y X' Y X' Y' **U**(') (14q*)

**U**(') Y X Y' X Y' X' **U**(') (14q*)

X Y X' Y X' Y' **U2** (14q*)

Y X Y' X Y' X' **U2** (14q*)

and furthermore,

**D2** =

R L F B R' L' **U2** F B R L F' B' (14q*)

R L F' B' R' L' **U2** F B R' L' F' B' (14q*)

R L' F B R' L **U2** F B' R L F' B (14q*)

R L' F' B' R' L **U2** F' B R' L' F B' (14q*)

R' L F B R L' **U2** F' B R L F B' (14q*)

R' L F' B' R L' **U2** F B' R' L' F' B (14q*)

R' L' F B R L **U2** F' B' R L F B (14q*)

R' L' F' B' R L **U2** F' B' R' L' F B (14q*)

F B R L F' B' **U2** R L F B R' L' (14q*)

F B R' L' F' B' **U2** R L F' B' R' L' (14q*)

F B' R L F' B **U2** R' L F B R L' (14q*)

F B' R' L' F' B **U2** R L' F' B' R' L (14q*)

F' B R L F B' **U2** R L' F B R' L (14q*)

F' B R' L' F B' **U2** R' L F' B' R L' (14q*)

F' B' R L F B **U2** R' L' F B R L (14q*)

F' B' R' L' F B **U2** R' L' F' B' R L (14q*)