# Sylow Subgroups of the Rubik's Cube Group

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory, rubiks-cube

The [Rubik's Cube Group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubik%27s_Cube_group) has order $2^{27} 3^{14} 5^3 7^2 11$. What is known about the Sylow subgroups of this group? Do they have an intuitive meaning with regards to the symmetry of the cube?

Comment: This problem is amenable to the free software GAP: see [here (39.13-1)](https://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/ref/chap39.html#X7AA351308787544C) and [here](https://www.gap-system.org/Doc/Examples/rubik.html).

Comment: Here is the [tag:gap] tag. If you're happy with computing the subgroups, then I suggest you add it with an [edit].

Comment: There are even questions having both `gap` and `rubiks-cube` tags, e.g. [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1641110/proof-that-the-rubik-s-cube-group-is-2-generated)